# Why is Linux syscall return type "long"?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am reading *Linux Kernel Development*, 3rd ed., to learn about the kernel implementation and design. Chapter 5 is about syscalls. The author shows an example of a syscall declaration that is defined using the `SYSCALL_DEFINE0` macro, which in that particular example expands to:

```
asmlinkage long sys_getpid(void)
```

He further says that:

> [...] For compatibility between 32- and 64-bit systems, system calls defined to return an int in user-space return a long in the kernel.

He doesn't go any deeper than that, and I can't exactly understand why it is that way. Why is the use of `long` related to 32- and 64-bit systems? Why can't we return a plain `int`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because on many [64 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) machines (e.g. x86-64) for the common GCC compiler `sizeof(int)==4` but `sizeof(void*)==8 && sizeof(long)==8`; This is called the I32LP64 (or just LP64) [data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model)

For instance, compile and run the following program on a Linux/x86-64 system:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main ()
{
  printf ("sizeof(int)=%d\n", (int) sizeof (int));
  printf ("sizeof(intptr_t)=%d\n", (int) sizeof (intptr_t));
  printf ("sizeof(short)=%d\n", (int) sizeof (short));
  printf ("sizeof(long)=%d\n", (int) sizeof (long));
  printf ("sizeof(long long)=%d\n", (int) sizeof (long long));
  printf ("sizeof(void*)=%d\n", (int) sizeof (void *));
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling on my system with `gcc -Wall s.c -o s` and running `./s` on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 ([i3770k](http://ark.intel.com/products/65523) processor, [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/).2):

```
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(intptr_t)=8
sizeof(short)=2
sizeof(long)=8
sizeof(long long)=8
sizeof(void*)=8
```

after compiling in 32 bits mode using `gcc -m32 -Wall s.c -o s32` and running `./s32`:

```
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(intptr_t)=4
sizeof(short)=2
sizeof(long)=4
sizeof(long long)=8
sizeof(void*)=4
```

<sup>I'm getting the same output if compiling for x32 using `gcc -mx32 -O3 -Wall s.c  -o sx32`!</sup>

BTW, perhaps the better question is why not use `intptr_t` .... I have no idea (probably, a matter of habits; [when Linus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Linux) first started to code his kernel, the [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard -defining `<stdint.h>` and  `intptr_t`- did not exist yet).

Read more about [ABIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), in particular read carefully the [X86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf%E2%80%8E) (see also [x32 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)...)  and the wikipage on [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: So this means that syscalls returning a pointer will return it as `long`?

Comment: @AndreyT, gcc 4.8.1 on my x86-64 returns 8 for `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: I'm running x86-64 with gcc 4.6.3 and it returns 8 for `sizeof(long)` too.

Comment: OK, it must be a confusion on my part. Indeed, it is 8.

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models also says that Linux and most Unix systems user LP64 data model - that's why. I wonder why not using `intptr_t`.

Comment: Be very careful when speaking about syscalls returning pointers! In which address space???

Comment: Hum, right... I don't know, it just popped into my head when you mentioned `void *` and `intptr_t`, I got the idea that they used `long` just because of pointers. For example, I imagine that syscalls implementing `brk()` and similar functions must return some pointer to a user-space process' address space, no?

Comment: do you mean to say that long is used because it would be architecture independent?

Comment: Just still do not know why using `long` in syscalls

Comment: I guess for an historical reason. Linux is a code base of millions of lines, some of which 20 years old